# Scraping Book Prices

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a scrape app, and I'm running in to problems. My PHP Curl code isn't pulling up the pages with the price of the books. It's returning me to the web root of the domain.

I'm trying to search the site by ISBN.

I've been bashing my head against the wall for days. Any help will be most appreciated!

Code:

```
<form method="post" for="new-search" name="SearchTerm" class='form-validate' id="SearchTerm" action="index.php">
    <textarea rows="3" name="SearchTerm" id="SearchTerm" cols="40" class="validate-required error"></textarea><div class="error" id="SearchTerm-error">
    <br>                        
    <button class="search primary" type="submit">continue</button>

</form>


<?php

/*
echo("<pre>");print_r($_GET);echo("</pre>");
echo("<pre>");print_r($_POST);echo("</pre>");
*/

$isbn = $_POST['SearchTerm'];


$userAgent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;rv:1.8.1.16) Gecko/20080702 Firefox/2.0.0.16';

$fields = array(
    'url' => ("http://www.bookleberry.com/Search/SearchKeyword"),
    'qurl' => ("http://www.bookleberry.com/Search/SearchKeyword/" . $_POST['SearchTerm']),
    'SearchTerm' => ($_POST['SearchTerm']),
    'Page' => ('1'),
    'class' => ('textfield validate-required'),
    'for' => ('new-search'),
    'result-count' => ('1'),
    'status' => 'success',
);

$SearchTerm = ($fields['SearchTerm']);
$url = ($fields['url']);
$Page = ($fields['Page']);


echo("<pre>");
print_r($fields);
echo("</pre>");

if ($isbn != NULL){

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        echo "before curl_exec:<br>";
        echo "curl_errno=". curl_errno($ch) ."<br>";
        echo "curl_error=". curl_error($ch) ."<br>";
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "?SearchTerm=$SearchTerm");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9999999);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
        "Accept: application/json"
    ));




    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print $result;


print "<pre>\n";
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));  // get error info

?>
```

Comment: Off-hand I would say because the content appears to be AJAX-populated. Scraping with PHP/CURL isn't going to get you far, you need to intercept the AJAX call, and get the result that javascript is using in the background.

Answer (score 4):

Don't hurt your head, use it!

- Install [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).
- Do a request using the browser, look in fiddler to exactly what is posted. This includes all headers, cookies and form variables.
- Do a post using your code, examine fiddler again
- Compare the differences between the two and adjust your script.
- Repeat.

Also it helps to install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Using the copy Xpath, and putting that into a php DOM xpath query makes scraping fun and easy!

Comment: I like the DOM Xpath Query idea for webscrapping

Comment: @emailenin - Just remember to remove the `<tbody>` elements that firebug puts in

Comment: The steps you provided, are the ones I always use when scraping a website ;)

Comment: And also, you should compare the source returned by IE and Firefox. Doesn't seem to be exactly the same all the time! (attribute names in tags, etc)!